# MEAn stack grunt error

Tags: gruntjs, mean-stack

I am using MEAN stack and create an custom package and install that package using

`cd folder-name`

`npm install <package-name>`

then

`grunt --force`

But it gives a lot of errors which are very hard to fix. Please see below

**Failed to open socket on port 5858, waiting 1000 ms before retrying**

**Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.**

```
Running "hook" task
>> Starting hooked tasks.

Running "clean:0" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 54 files lint free.

Running "csslint:src" (csslint) task
>> 6 files lint free.

Running "concurrent:tasks" (concurrent) task
Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
debugger listening on port 5858
Failed to open socket on port 5858, waiting 1000 ms before retrying
Fatal error: Port 35729 is already in use by another process.


Execution Time (2015-03-09 06:11:34 UTC)
loading tasks  5.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 82%
watch          1.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 18%
Total 7s

    Warning:  Used --force, continuing.


    Failed to open socket on port 5858, waiting 1000 ms before retrying

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1135:5)
    at ExpressEngine.beginBootstrap
```

tried to fix by changing in *gruntFile.js* by setting

```
 watch: {
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            },
```

but no luck..

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to kill the previous instance of your program to fire it up again. The old instance is running and using the port that is needed by the new instance.

Comment: I did..how to kill? i just do `ctrl+Z` to stop the command on terminal

Comment: Ctrl-Z puts to sleep. The devices are probably still engaged. You have to kill -KILL the process or do Ctrl-Z